# linking/building portaudio static library

Tags: gcc, makefile, static-libraries, qmake, portaudio

I'm trying to use the static library from portaudio by putting **"libportaudio.a"** in my project after compiling portaudio (by doing "./configre && make" and then i took the file in lib/.libs/).

As this is a qt project, my Makefile Lib line look like this:

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/home/larose/babel/BabelAudio/lib -Lportaudio -Llibspeex -Llibspeexdsp -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread
```

In my .pro i have :

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib -Lportaudio -Llibspeex -Llibspeexdsp
```

But when i try doing make, the result is :

```
SpeakThread.cpp:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `Pa_OpenStream'
SpeakThread.cpp:(.text+0x3c7): undefined reference to `Pa_OpenStream'
SpeakThread.cpp:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `Pa_StartStream'
SpeakThread.cpp:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `Pa_StartStream'
SpeakThread.cpp:(.text+0x3e4): undefined reference to `Pa_IsStreamActive'
```

Is there anything special to do when doing ./configure to make the library portable, or simply something to change in the Makefile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `-l` not `-L`

```
-lportaudio
```